# systemctl --user cannot start docker containers on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: docker, systemd, ubuntu-18.04, systemctl, ubuntu-20.04

I am in the process of migrating some services from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. In 18.04 I run these services under a non-root user. All these services start a docker container, and they're working just fine. Under Ubuntu 20.04 these services no longer start.

To illustrate, here's a very simple `~/.config/systemd/user/hello-world.service` that works fine on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
# -*-systemd-*-
[Unit]
Description=Hello world
After=network.service
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
TimeoutStartSec=0

ExecStartPre=/bin/echo user = $USER
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull hello-world
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run \
  --name hello-world \
  --rm -a STDIN -a STDOUT -a STDERR \
  hello-world

ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop -t 2 %n

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I run the container in the shell directly as the non-root user and it runs fine, both on the 18.04 machine, as well as on the 20.04 machine:

```
/usr/bin/docker pull hello-world
/usr/bin/docker run \
  --name hello-world \
  --rm -a STDIN -a STDOUT -a STDERR \
  hello-world
```

For systemd I run the following:

```
systemctl --user enable hello-world.service
systemctl --user start hello-world.service
```

On Ubuntu 18.04 everything runs as expected when I investigate the out with `journalctl -xe -f`.

On Ubuntu 20.04 I get the dreaded:

```
Sep 15 14:56:26 m4 docker[107614]: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/images/create?fromImage=hello-world&tag=latest: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

I checked the permissions, groups and everything seems to be correct. Again, if I run the docker directly in the command line while logged in as `username`, docker runs just fine.

```
root@m4:/etc/apt> ll /var/run/docker.sock 
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Sep 15 14:08 /var/run/docker.sock=
root@m4:/etc/apt> grep docker /etc/group
docker:x:998:docker,username
```

The only thing that's different is that on 18.04 systemd is at version 237, while on 20.04 is at version 245.

Docker is the same on both machines:

```
Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe
```

Both versions of systemd show the user echoed in `ExecStartPre` as being my non-root user.

It looks like systemd 245 is starting the docker process under the wrong user and/or group. Any thoughts?

### Update

As @larsks suggested, I replaced `$USER` with `/usr/bin/id`. Here's the output I received:

```
Sep 15 21:36:09 m4 id[122143]: uid=1001(username) gid=1001(username) groups=1001(username)
Sep 15 21:36:09 m4 docker[122144]: Using default tag: latest
Sep 15 21:36:09 m4 docker[122144]: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/images/create?fromImage=hello-world&tag=latest: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

`username` is part of the `docker` group, as shown above.

Comment: Replace `/bin/echo user = $USER` in your systemd unit with `/usr/bin/id`. This will output your uid, primary gid, and all additional groups of which the user is a member. Update the question to include that output.

Comment: Thanks @larsks, I updated my question to use `/usr/bin/id` instead of `$USER`. @Michael, I'm starting systemctl as `username` using `systemctl --user start hello-world`. If I were to start it as root it will likely work, I already have other systemd services that start docker like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your systemd user unit doesn't specify a `Group=`, thus the user's default group is used. Since `docker` is not the default group, systemd doesn't start the process with this group.

Set `Group=docker` in the `[Service]` section of the unit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @michael-hampton. Unfortunately that doesn't work: since I'm starting the systemctl process as a non-privileged user, changing groups is not allowed, even though the user is part of the group.

```
[...]: hello-world.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: Operation not permitted
[...]: hello-world.service: Changing group credentials failed: Operation not permitted
[...]: hello-world.service: Failed at step GROUP spawning /usr/bin/id: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: BTW, `username` is in the right group too, this is what `groups` returns just before starting `systemctl`:

`uid=1001(username) gid=1001(username) groups=1001(username),998(docker)`

Comment: That's strange, a user unit ought to be able to set the group. You might have run into a bug in systemd, or in Ubuntu's implementation of it (why on earth are you using Ubuntu anyway?!). In any case it should certainly work as a system unit, but since you're using Ubuntu you can't easily let the user manage a system unit without using `sudo` which you might not want to allow.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. I ended up rebooting the machine, after the reboot it seem the problem went away and everything is working as expected with the original configuration.  I do need `username` to be in the `docker` group, but long-running services can now be run managed as regular users instead of root. More than few hours wasted on this :(

Comment: As to why I'm using Ubuntu: for LTS. I've been running Debian in the past, but support for older OS versions is dropped too soon IMO. I have machines where upgrading the OS is too much of a pain, especially when you run everything in a container that's kept up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [example docker container unit file](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/init/systemd/docker.service) I believe what is missing is at least:

`After=docker.socket` in the [`[Unit]`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/init/systemd/docker.service#L4) section of the unit file and `Delegate=yes` in the [`[Service]`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/init/systemd/docker.service#L24) section so that

> so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers

Setting:

`KillMode=process`

so that

> kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup

seems like a good idea to me as well. I would recommend to take a look at the linked example and configure the unit file accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out an old-fashioned reboot fixed the problem. :(

Before that I had tried restarting systemd which didn't fix the problem. I still don't know what happened, probably I hit some bug in the kernel and systemd configuration.

Kernel: `5.4.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu`

Systemd:

```
systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.2)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```